# What is the Excel IdMso of "Insert Copied Cells"

Tags: vba, excel, vsto

I am looking to find the idmso of the "Insert Copied Cells" Excel ribbon button found under Home->Cells->Insert.

The "Insert Copied Cells" ribbon button is only visible if you have something on your clipboard.

The idmso of the "Insert" splitbutton is "InsertCellstMenu". However, of all the sites that list the Excel idmsos and even Microsoft official spreadsheet of idmsos, none of them seem to list the idmso for "Insert Copied Cells". http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3582

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the idMso is "CellsInsertDialog". The confusing part is that the text of the ribbon button changes depending on what you've done before you show it (like if you have done a cut or a copy). It could be "Insert Cells", "Insert Cells...", "Insert Copied Cells", "Insert Copied Cells...", "Insert Cut Cells", or "Insert Cut Cells..." depending on if you have anything in your clipboard and if your current selection is a range, a column, or a row.